# How to add delays for launch configurations in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, launch-configuration

I have a launch group with several launch configurations. When it is ran, all configurations are launched one after the other quickly. I'm not sure if one launch needs to "return" in some fashion in order for the next to start.

I would like to add a delay between some of the launches. Either a manual time duration: launch1, wait 2 seconds, launch2; or some way to tell the next launch that it can happen now.

Is there any way to do it in Eclipse (I'm on 4.5.2)? Maybe a plugin or an option in the launch configuration? I'm also open for a script option if someone can guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse Oxygen this options became available as a [Launch Group](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/platform.php#launch-groups) launch configuration. Go to `Run > Run Configurations...`, under `Launch Group` add a new configuration and then add the configurations you want to launch.

It's possible to set a delay in the `Post launch action`:

[image]